# Google Analytics Dimensions Not Feeding Through

Tags: google-analytics

I have setup custom dimensions as follows

[image]

My source code shows as this:

```
<script>
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Manager');
    ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Recruitment');
    ga('set', 'dimension3', 'Leave');

</script>
```

It's been in place for 24 hours. However when I go to my Google Analytics account > Home > Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages, and then add any of the custom dimensions I've created, no data is brought back.

Am I doing something terribly wrong or does everything look ok?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reorder your calls. By the time you set the custom dimensions, your pageview is already sent, without those.

So your code should be:

```
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');

ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Manager');
ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Recruitment');
ga('set', 'dimension3', 'Leave');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

(I assume, that your Analytics tracker is initialised, and your pageview is collected properly, but without custom dimensions set.)

Further reference:

[Custom dimensions & metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) (see Collection)

[Developer guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets)